# Playing jukebox style MP3 s by GPIO , how does the code/directories work?

Tags: gpio, python

Having followed the adafruit "overview playing music with buttons raspberry pi" I thought I knew it all but then I wanted to play random files and then to scroll through the files and play them by button press.

couple notes: the mp3 files are in the same \home\pi directory as the python script. What I want is to flow through 4 separate music folders by genre, but don't know why adafruit neglected to address this topic.

The error(s) you ask? 
1)**"subprocess is not defined" What do I do?**
2)"the file could not be found to even play

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from os import listdir
import subprocess
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN)

mp3_files = [ f for f in listdir('.') if f[-4:] == '.mp3' ]

if not (len(mp3_files) > 0):
    print "No mp3 files found!"

print '--- Available mp3 files ---'
print mp3_files
print '--- Press button #1 to select mp3, button #2 to play current. ---'

index = 0
while True:
    if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
        index += 1
        if index >= len(mp3_files):
            index = 0
        print "--- " + mp3_files[index] + " ---"

    if (GPIO.input(24) == False):
        subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', mp3_files[index]])
        print '--- Playing ' + mp3_files[index] + ' ---'
        print '--- Press button #3 to clear playing mp3s. ---'
        sleep(1)

    if (GPIO.input(25) == False):
        subprocess.call(['killall', 'mpg123'])
        print '--- Cleared all existing mp3s. ---'

    sleep(0.1);
```

Comment: I've got a suspicion it's your quotes. Could you try replacing the single quotes around 'mpg123' in your subprocess.Popen lines with double quotes - "mpg123"?

Comment: thank you honestly I am excited to try that. Also In my real code the directory is  ----  for f in listdir('\home\pi') ------. This is where my mp3s are too.

Comment: before adding quotes I noticed "import subprocess" was missing. So now the problem is that when pressing button 1 the entire list of mp3s is printed and you can not cycle through them as you would want to >>?

Answer (score -2):

The first mistake I see in this code is on the print command.

```
print "No mp3 files found!"
```

...should be enclosed in brackets, like this.

```
print ("No mp3 files found!")
```

...the next set of print commands too should also look like this, with opening and closing brackets.

```
print ('--- Available mp3 files ---')

print (mp3_files)

print ('--- Press button #1 to select mp3, button #2 to play current. ---')
```

Otherwise it throws an error when you come to run it.

There were other problems I found too for the GPIO setup, on the debug output it kept polling through the GPIO instructions, as though it wasn't sure if the pins were high or low, so I made these changes which fixed it all by pulling the initial state of the pins to HIGH.

```
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

Comment: The shown `print` statements are ok for Python 2.x and are certainly not related to the reported problems (i.e. in this case the OP would have said to have gotten a `SyntaxError`).